# VS Crashes when using T-SQL OPENJSON and SELECT *

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

When using the below code the VS 2019 crashed without fail. Though it was originally working, possibly prior to a recent update (or upgrade to VS 2019 from VS 2017)

The error message implied a too long identifier and related to a specific file. I temp resolved this by accessing my project via Team Explorer as opposed to startup window. It resurfaced as soon as I edited the file. So I went line-by-line to find the culprit, the code below is the culprit. I cannot understand why it causes the crash.

---

```
DECLARE @Characteristics nvarchar(4000) = (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Details)
WITH ([Firstname] nvarchar(256) N'$.firstname',[Lastname] nvarchar(256) N'$.lastname') FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER);
```

---

It's a legitimate command and SQL accepts including deployments. For my purposes and because I control the WITH clause, "SELECT *", is an acceptable deviation from my practice of stating the columns in the SELECT clause.

VS no longer crashes now that I declare each expected column in the SELECT clause. If somebody has an alternative resolution to solving this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue again, and am unable to do so. Let me add that when I first solved it by accessing via Team Explorer it seemed fixed for a couple of days but re-occurred. As at the time of this comment, the environment is stable so I still feel strongly this is the fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show enough - at least for me - to understand your issue completely...

What I get:

- You want to use `SELECT *`
- You are *controlling* the `WITH` clause (I assume: You build it dynamically in your application)

You did not show the actual error message (please do this the next time), but I get, that the error depends on the difference of

- `SELECT * FROM ...`
- `SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM ...`

I cannot reproduce your issue, but I guess, that there are more sources involved in your actual statement and that `*` might include more than you tell us.

Did you try to use a table alias after the `WITH`?

```sql
DECLARE @Details NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'[{"a":"a1", "b":"b1"},{"a":"a2","b":"b2"}]';

SELECT
(
    SELECT tbl.*              --<-- Using "tbl.*" instead of "*"
    FROM OPENJSON(@Details)
    WITH(a NVARCHAR(100)
        ,b NVARCHAR(100)) tbl --<-- table alias "tbl"
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);
```

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I will see if I can reproduce it and if so, will add an image of the error message.